# Invalid redeclaration of "StyleKitSettableImage" in Paintcode

Tags: swift, xcode, paintcode, redeclaration

I have two Paintcode Stylekit swift classes to write two different images into two different views. The first one works well, but when I import the second one these two function

```
@objc protocol StyleKitSettableImage {
    func setImage(image: UIImage!)
}
```

and

```
@objc protocol StyleKitSettableSelectedImage {
    func setSelectedImage(image: UIImage!)
}
```

had a red warning, invalid redeclaration of `StyleKitSettableImage` and `StyleKitSettableSelectedImage`. I know that invalid redeclaration means that there are two functions with the same name, but these func are in two different classes. So the question is: if I had to import more the one StyleKit class in Xcode, how could I fix this error?

EDIT: maybe i must have only one style kit file whit all drawing method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have to create one StyleKit class with as canvas as I need; no more classes